# Firebase получение данных по ключевым словам

Tags: reactjs, база-данных, firebase

Имеется проблема, как можно получить коллекцию пользователей с ПОХОЖИМ именем, а не точь-в-точь таким же, облазил все, не смог найти ответа.
Например, пользователь вводит *Да*, нужно чтобы выводились пользователи с именами *Данила*, *Даниил*, *Даня*. И т.д. Суть, думаю понятна.

```js
const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
const [userNameDebounced] = useDebounce(userName, 150)

const [values, loading, error] = useCollectionData<IFirebase>(
    query(collection(database, 'users') as Query<IFirebase, DocumentData>),
    where('name', '==', userNameDebounced) as Options &
      IDOptions<IFirebase> &
      InitialValueOptions<IFirebase[]>
  )

console.log(values)
```

За перерендеры пока не важно, главное понять как получать данные не с таким же именно именем веденным в инпуте, а с похожим на него.

Comment: Какой критерий похожести? И код с картинки на текст замените в вопросе

Comment: С firebase не работал. Однако нашел там оператор startAt и startEnd - можно попробовать их использовать(а вот как - хз, по доке сходу не разобрался, примеров мало)

Comment: @SwaD, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715093/firebase-startat-string-only-takes-first-character нашел ответ, если интересно, можете почитать, спасибо большое что дали наводку.

Comment: Ссылка это хорошо. Если оформите ответ, как вы решили данную задачу, будет лучше. Останется для будущих поколений ru-стэка

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде нет ничего плохого, что-то не так с вашими ожиданиями.

Функция `startAt()` работает как отправная точка вашего запроса, а не как фильтр. Таким образом, в вашем случае он найдет первое появление слова «Джон» и вернет все, начиная с этого момента (включая Джоэла, Кевина, Тима и т. д.).

К сожалению, нет прямого способа выполнить запрос, в котором findKey содержит строку «John». Но, **к счастью**, есть (частичное) решение проблемы с помощью `endAt()`.

Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

`orderBy="findKey"&startAt="john"&endAt="john\uf8ff"`

Здесь `\uf8ff` — последний символ Юникода (поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь).

Благодаря этому вы можете запрашивать значения, начинающиеся с «Джон», например «Джонни», «Джон». Но не «1джон», «джом» или «Джоэл».

***Ответ переведен с английского языка. На данный вопрос ответил - André Kool, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715093/firebase-startat-string-only-takes-first-character)***